# How to make Ansible with_fileglob include hidden files?

Tags: ansible, hidden-files, file-globs

I'm using the following task in my Ansible script to copy all files from a local data folder to the server:

```
- name: copy basic files to folder
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: ~/data/
    mode: 755
    owner: "www-data"
    group: "www-data"
  with_fileglob:
    - ../files/data/*
```

This works fine, except for that it skips hidden files (such as `.htaccess`).

Does anybody know how I can make `with_fileglob` also include hidden files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ansible [uses](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/fileglob.py#L37) Python's [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html).

> If the directory contains files starting with `.` they won’t be matched by default.
>
> ```
> >>> import glob
> >>> glob.glob('*.gif')
> ['card.gif']
> >>> glob.glob('.c*')
> ['.card.gif']
> ```

Add `.*` explicitly to the list of patterns.

Comment: I just found the answer myself as well. But I'll accept your one. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Ok, found the answer myself. I found that `with_fileglob` simply calls the python [glob.glob()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) function. So after some fideling around I found  just had to add a fileglob with `.*` to it:

```
- name: copy basic files to folder
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: ~/data/
    mode: 755
    owner: "www-data"
    group: "www-data"
  with_fileglob:
    - ../files/data/*
    - ../files/data/.*
```

Comment: I was faster by 18 seconds ;)

Comment: You're right! And you're getting the credits! Thanks and I wish you a beautiful day!